# Reason for massive change in signalr performance?

Tags: performance, azure, signalr

I have written a basic signalr hub that accepts a call from a client, updates the database and then pings a notification out to all clients.

```
public class ElementHub : Hub
{
    public void RenameElement(Guid elementId, string elementName)
    {
        //save details of rename

        //notify clients
        Clients.elementRenamed(elementId, elementName, DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on my development machine - all updates are instantaneous (near enough) - but when I publish this to Windows Azure website I start to see some odd behaviour.

After publication, the *first* notification that passes through the hub is still pretty much instantaneous - maybe a seconds delay.  But the *second* notification is sometimes delayed by as much as 30 seconds!

I've included the server timestamp in the notification so I can confirm that the server is responding quickly enough.  The problem is presumably somewhere in the transport.

I'm new to signalr so I don't really even know where to look.  Can anyone suggest what might be causing this behaviour or how I can debug it?

Comment: @dfowler yes, just using the free trial

Comment: There's a bug right now with buffering, see https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/510. You can work around this for now by using longpolling. We're working on this.

Comment: @dfowler fantastic!  Not fantastic there's a bug, but fantastic that longPolling solves the problem!  Can you make it answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug right now with buffering and Azure Websites, see http://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/510. You can work around this for now by using longpolling. We're working on this in the meantime.